# Migrate Case Comment Data

Tags: case, email2case

I'm doing a data migration from one Salesforce system to another and need to migrate all of our Case Comments. Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm adding a LegacyId field to all of our objects so I can maintain all of the relationships between the Case Comments and Cases and I don't think it's possible to add a custom field to the Case Comments object. Any advice?

Thanks,
Rochelle

Comment: you might consider creating a `CaseCommentLegacy__c` object and make it a M-D to Case.  You definitely cannot customize `CaseComment`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Import2? We migrate Case Comments by default, along with your other objects such as Cases, Attachments, Customers and Organizations. We also retain the relationships between these objects, so there is no mapping or special configuration needed on your part.

You can see how this will work with your own data with a free sample import: https://www.import2.com/salesforceservicecloud/from/salesforceservicecloud

Hope this helps! FYI I work at Import2 in end-user support for data migrations. If you try the sample and have any trouble, you can always reach out to me.

Comment: Can you please disclose your relationship with this product more explicitly, if there is one?

Comment: I work at Import2, mentioned above, in end-user support for data migrations

Comment: That's the thing, you don't really mention it other than your use of "we".

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't more clear! I've edited the post to reflect my role more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

I am marketing manager at Data2CRM. If you are looking for a way to test your Salesforce to Microsoft Dynamics migration and vice versa, an automated migration service Data2CRM can help you perform a transfer. You can take advantage of a free Demo Migration to:

- explore if the SaaS fits your requirements
- get a rough estimation of the time the procedure takes
- identify the bottlenecks to exclude them before data import.

In case you are interested, stop by and perform a trial run: https://app.data2crm.com/.

Kind regards, 
Nataliia

Comment: If you are posting an answer containing or promoting a commercial service or app please make your affiliation with it clear in the post.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I will take it into consideration.